# How to test components with Cypress in a Laravel/Inertiajs/Vue3 stack

Tags: vue.js, cypress, inertiajs

I'm testing out Cypress for the first time with my Vue components in my Laravel/Inertia app and I'm struggling to understand how to correctly stub global functions so that I can isolate my testing to just the component functionality.

For example in many components I call a global translation function `__()` which I have imported though the Ligua library in my app.js as part of my Inertia app.

I don't need to test this function so my thinking was that I should stub it in my test instead:

```
describe('ConversationStatus', () => {
  it('renders', () => {
    cy.stub(window, '__').returns('some text')

    cy.mount(ConversationStatus)

  })
})
```

However, I get the error `Cannot stub non-existent own property __`. So do I need to import the same Lingua library in my test so it exists before I can stub it?

If so, can anyone point me in the right direction for how to correctly do that?

here is my app.js in case it helps to see how I currently import it into my project:

```
import { createApp, h, ref, provide } from 'vue';
import { createInertiaApp } from '@inertiajs/vue3';
import { resolvePageComponent } from 'laravel-vite-plugin/inertia-helpers';
import { ZiggyVue } from '../../vendor/tightenco/ziggy/dist/vue.m';
import { LinguaVue } from 'lingua-js';
import { Lingua } from './lingua';
import { createPinia } from 'pinia';


const appName = window.document.getElementsByTagName('title')[0]?.innerText || 'Laravel';


createInertiaApp({
    title: (title) => `${title} - ${appName}`,
    resolve: (name) => resolvePageComponent(`./Pages/${name}.vue`, import.meta.glob('./Pages/**/*.vue')),
    setup({ el, App, props, plugin }) {

        const app =  createApp({ render: () => h(App, props) })
            .use(plugin)
            .use(ZiggyVue, Ziggy)
            .use(LinguaVue, {
                locale: props.initialPage.props.locale,
                Lingua
            })
            .use(createPinia())
            .mount(el);


        return app;
    },
    progress: {
        color: '#4B5563',
    },

});
```